# EMC test failure: LC filter

Tags: inductor, emc, low-pass, emi-filtering

I am currently developing my first product which needs to fulfill EU EMC requirements.

Below you can see the first result out of the EMC lab (radiated emission test):

[image: EMC test - failed]

One can clearly see the 16 MHz clock frequency and the radiation out of the product seem to go over the power lines through multiple connectors from the main PCB.

This assumption also comes from the following results of a measurement without having the connectors attached:

[image: EMC test - passed without wires]

So, now I am designing an update and beside optimizing the layout regarding the crystal, uC decoupling, trace length reductions, and provisions for ferrite beads on the signal lines, but I am not really sure about one countermeasure - an LC filter.

Here I would be very thankful to get some help.

**Questions:**

1. I want to add an LC filter on every power line right before the connector. But here I have the first issue - which cut-off frequency needs to be used? Is it the frequency of the first peak (32 MHz) or, as I read a lot, 1/10th of the first peak (3.2 MHz)?
2. Filter: I have a connector which has 1 x 12 V power and 3x switched low-side power (PWM/MOSFET). Does it make any sense to add filters to these lines, or is it just the power line which makes sense to filter?

Comment: You need to do one of two things: either 1) analyze where the noise is coming from in your circuit and address each cause individually, or 2) slap ferrite beads all over the place in the hope that it'll clean up the noise enough. Using a lossy ferrite bead instead of a standard inductor for an LC filter should give you somewhat better performance than just the inductor.

Comment: I'm sure you don't have a full EMC test lab at your disposal, but figuring out where noise is coming from can be a lot easier if you have an E-field or H-field probe. Even better if you have both.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. Actually I was in full EMC lab and we are 99% sure that it's the 16MHz crystal on power which is creating the noise. So ideally with better decoupling of the uC (currently only one 100nF cap at each VDD/VSS pin pair) we will already get rid of the issue. But I want to do a "just in case this is not enough" thing. Ferrit beads are also considered to be taken instead/in addition to the LC filter, but in this question it's really about the LC filter I want to at least provide the footprints for, even if I do not populate them and first trying with a ferrit bead.

Comment: Far more information is needed to confirm the diagnosis (schematic, PCB and assembly layout, arrangement in the test chamber), but, whose bright idea was it to plot the polarizations in identical colors?!

Comment: As for 2, no filter on GND except for very rare cases. You want your GND as low impedance as possible. Can you share schematic and layout? How many layers does your PCB have and what’s your stackup? What does your decoupling situation look like?

Comment: Is the 16MHz noise from the clock, or from *logic* switching at that frequency?  Because a clock is pretty high-impedance...

Comment: @Daniel Yes, you were in an EMC lab for that testing, but using an EMC lab is *incredibly* expensive. I doubt you have the ability to just make use of one whenever you want. E-field and H-field probes are types of probe you can get for any ordinary oscilloscope--ones good for proper quantitative measurements will run you a few thousand dollars, but you can make ones good for qualitative measurements from coax and tape. That'll be helpful to narrow down where the noise is coming from, even if you can't properly *measure* the noise with them.

Comment: I just added the layout and stackup in the question. Regarding the schematic I have to admit it is a total mess to understand - have to clean up before I can share that with anyone who maybe is doing this proffesionally :-)

Comment: @Hearth, thank you for the hint with the probes - using this coax+tape method sounds interesting. The reason I mentioned that I have been in a real lab was to underline that the source is pretty well identified.

Comment: @rdtsc, I am not sure on this question...how can I identify what it is? As a first response, we measured the part without having any software doing anything so for me this sound like really having the clock ticking in the power-what do you think?

Comment: @winny, thank you for the confirmation regarding GND - I was just unsure because these are the lines which are "switched". Layout and stackup was added in the question

Comment: @winny I understood that as, low-side switched loads, not a common ground.  Filtering in such location would probably be desirable. (What PWM?) Whether +V, SW or both need to be filtered, also depends on CM emissions. Much, much more information is needed.

Comment: @Daniel Why are there no connections between sections? These "layout" images almost look copy-pasted from local sections without routing between them. It looks eerie at the very least, and at the worst is very counterproductive.

Comment: @Tim,Winny, yes the better term is low side switched loads - sorry I am not a native english speaker.

Comment: @Tim. The layout is not finished yet I just wanted to provide it asap as I understand without it is hard to help. Of course connections still need to be done. I can update once it is finished. And yes until now I just copy pasted the local sections from the old layout and repositioned/added parts.

Comment: What... did you test, then?

Comment: @Tim, the old design which was tested had other issues (like pcb mounted led drivers) which were also identified as a emc mess and so a complete redesign is necessary...I know from this we can get completely other phenomenon, but that's why I focus on filtering and provisions for filtering

Comment: We really need the full layout. Is that an sd card? Are the traces crossing different reference planes without decoupling caps? More than likely there is an antenna on your board you aren’t considering. Just because it’s frequency is the same a crystal fundamentals doesn’t mean that’s the problem.

Comment: If 16 MHz harmonics are making you fail, try to put an RC filter on any 16 MHz signals. This helps tremendously. All clocks should have an RC on them. R at the driving source and C at the load. Good luck.

Comment: So somehow you are radiating the clock. There maybe is an antenna. It probably is a GND issue. Try to get ground layer as close as possible to signal layer and don’t split ground planes.

Answer (score 2):

Question 1 - If I'm interpreting your test results correctly, you are missing your spec by approximately 18 dB at (I think) 32 MHz.  That means you need to attenuate that frequency by at least 18 dB.  Hence the filter needs to be designed for a cutoff frequency of much less than 32 MHz, depending upon the order of the filter.

The peaks at 140 MHz and around 200 MHz are not directly related to the 16 MHz crystal oscillator.  The spectrum of the oscillator should roll off with increasing frequency.  So those frequencies are indicative of other parts of the circuit that are switching at ~140 MHz and ~200 MHz.

I know this solution probably isn't in your solution space, but this is one of the reasons we routinely shield cables, especially signal cables.  Input power filtering is usually taken care of with appropriate common mode filters.

Comment: Hey SteveSh, thank you for your answer, your point "Hence the filter needs to be designed for a cutoff frequency of much less than 32 MHz, depending upon the order of the filter." goes exactly in the direction I am asking for - I am currently thinking of a filter 2nd order. What would be the correct target frequency in this case and beside telling me if you know I of course would be interested to know how I can calculate this or if it's simple experience. A lot of times I read the cut off frequency should be 1/10th of the frequency you want to filter but without explanation. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Daniel a filter cut-off point is defined to be the frequency it attenuates 3dB. So obviously if you want to attenuate something more than 3dB, you want the cut-off to happen earlier. The filter order defines the slope, which defines where to put the cut-off to get the requires attenuation at the required frequency.

Comment: Hello Just me, thank you for your answer. I think I got it now. I found a cool tool which gives you the attenuation at a specific frequency for a defined filter: http://www.falstad.com/afilter/

Comment: But now I have a following question...for what do I have to watch out in regards to too low cut off frequency? Because my first (probably incorrect) thought now is "ok, I just go extremely low with the cut off frequency, like 100kHz, and then I simply eliminate all spikes in the MHz range"

Comment: As information, the main power supply I am using has an fosc of 110kHz...is this maybe something to consider like staying above this f buy then as low as possible?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to add an LC filter on every power line right before the
> connector. But here I have the first issue - which cutoff frequency
> needs to be used? Is it the frequency of the first peak (32 MHz) or,
> as I read a lot, 1/10th of the first peak (3.2 MHz).

Do something easier first and add a ceramic 0.1uf cap between the terminals and ground of the connectors while you are testing. If you use wire, use a high gauge with lower inductance (not 30awg), the higher the better. Usually it's a good idea also in future designs to have connectors with the option for shielding in the case of radiating cables. Make sure all cables are twisted to minimize radiation.

> Filter: I have a connector which has 1x 12 V power and 3x switched GND
> (PWM/MOSFET), does it make any sense to add filters to the GND lines
> or is it just the power line which makes sense to filter?

Have two things you can do. either make the impedance high enough in or before the cable the high frequency signals will not travel down the cable. Another option is to short the high frequency signals to ground with capacitance. One problem with this is you need to make sure that your capacitance does not have parasitic inductance (parasitic inductance arises from any copper traces, vias or even the leads of capacitors, which creates small amounts of series inductance that can block high frequency signals, these effects must be accounted for when creating a shunt to ground, at lol at the impedance graph of the shunt capacitor)